# Why xdotool is not clicking when restoring position?

Tags: command-line, xdotool

Why `xdotool` is not clicking when restoring position?

```
 xdotool mousemove --sync 4000 1000      click 1         mousemove restore
```

If I don't restore the position, it works, example:

```
 xdotool mousemove --sync 4000 1000      click 1
```

EDIT1: What I've tried

```
eval "$(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)"
xdotool mousemove --sync 4000 1000
xdotool click 1
xdotool mousemove --screen $SCREEN $X $Y
```

To my surprise, it also does not click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application may need you to wait for it to get focus before it accepts button events. If possible, use `windowactivate` to get the window focused first, or if not, do a short `sleep .2` say, after the mousemove and before the click.